# toFixed(0) or Math.ciel error?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, appery.io

I seem to have a slight problem.

This is my code:

```
var rc1FrontMM = Number(Apperyio("rc1FrontMM").val());
var rc1RearMM = Number(Apperyio("rc1RearMM").val());
var rc1TyreRatio1 = Number(Apperyio("rc1TyreRatio1").val());
var rc1TyreRatio2 = Number(Apperyio("rc1TyreRatio2").val());

var rc1TyreRatio1 = rc1RearMM / rc1FrontMM;
var rc1TyreRatio2 = rc1RearMM / rc1FrontMM;

Apperyio('rc1TyreRatio1').val(rc1TyreRatio1.toFixed(2));
Apperyio('rc1TyreRatio2').val(rc1TyreRatio2.toFixed(2));
```

When I test, the returned result (screenshot attached) is "0.00" when if we used Rear: 6165 & Front: 4745, the result should be: 1.299262381454162, but with toFixed(2) it should be: 1.29, not 0.00

Any idea's what has gone wrong?

[image: the problem]

Comment: The result should be 1.30, not 1.29 :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the variables `rc1FrontMM` and `rc1RearMM` contains the correct form values, and that the variable `rc1TyreRatio1` is indeed 1.299...?

Comment: @GjermundDahl rc1FrontMM & rc1RearMM have over 150 variable's to choose from each through a pop-up menu. However, the two variable's I listed are just 2 out of 300 possible combination's, all read 0.00, it was easier to run off those 2 variable's then list 300 variable's with an unlimited combination.

It boil's down too, Rear / Front = Result & at the moment, result is always 0.00 not what it should be, eg: 1.29 (or 1.30)

Comment: Alright, if the variables read 0.00, the error is not necessarily related to the ratio calculation then :-)

Comment: @GjermundDahl it could be with the 300 variable's and how they are stored? I presently have them stored as number's, should I store them as strings instead? or Boolean?

Comment: @All, thank you for your help, I have solved it by placing in a 'calculate' button as the app is refusing to 'auto-calculate' which is unfortunate and the client has no choice but to accept.